# How to change color of searched text in TexStudio

Tags: color, texstudio

Currently, the searched texts in the Windowed viewer (pdf file) in TexStudio are displayed in light yellow which is hard to see. I wonder how to change the color (to darker color) for searched texts in pdf files of the Windowed viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Options -> Configure TeXstudio`, at `Internal PDF Viewer` option `Highlight Color.

The default color is `#FFFF003F`, I change to `#FF00003F`, it will produce a red highlight. I also added a little bit more time to be able to screenshot at `Highlight Duration`.

[image]

[image]